# Graph: Difference between coordinates and ordinals

Tags: graphing-functions

What is the difference between coordinates and ordinals on a graph

Answer (score 0):

On a graph, you probably mean [ordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinate) which is the $y$ coordinate.  The $x$ coordinate is the [absicca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa).  The two together are coordinates.